# create short int array in c like java short[]

Tags: java, c++, c

Java:

```
byte[] arr1=new byte[]{0x01};
String aa = "helloo";
short[] s1 = new short[1]; // **
s1[0] = 246;               // **

Object[] obj = new Object[]{s1,arr1,aa}
```

C:

```
signed char a1[] = {0x01};
char *str = "helloo";
short int st1[] = {246}; // **

char*  c [] = {st1,str1,c2};
```

Is `short int st1[] = {246}` correct? And I am getting this error:
"`illegal implicit conversion from 'short *' to 'char *'`".
How to assign short to char?

Comment: `char*` isn't an `Object`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: **short[] s1 = new short[1];
is not java code

Comment: Indeed, the error has nothing to do with the short array. What are you trying to accomplish with the last line?

Answer (score 3):

```
char*  c []
```

is an array of pointers, not an array of chars.

Use something like

```
short st1[] = { 246 };
char* str = "helloo";
char  c [] = {st1[0], str[0], str[1], str[2], str[3], str[4], str[5]};
```

`str[i]` gets individual characters, since 'char* str' points to the first element of an array.

If you need an array of string, then make it

```
char tmp[1024];
// itoa is the conversion of st1[0] to string
char* c[] = { itoa(st1[0], tmp, 10), str };
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do anyway. Store pointers, get string representation of numbers?

Comment: i am trying to pass str,short and other vaule to method and using those values in method.

Answer (score 1):

Cast `st1` to a `char*`. I.e.:

```
char*  c [] = {(char*)st1,str1,c2};
```

Note that you'll have to cast the pointer back to `short*` when accessing the elements it points to if you want to get the correct data.

Comment: thanks this works. but how to type cast short[] in this??         buffer[index]  = (byte)(((short[])obj[i])[0]>>>8 & 0x00ff);

Comment: In C that would be  ((short*)c[i])[0]     be careful though when you do this, so that you don't try to access data outside of the array boundaries.

Comment: when i store 246 in short variable it's storing it as -10 even in java also. so can you explain me why it's storing as -10?? thank you.

Comment: -10 is the signed 8-bit representation of the unsigned value 246. In Java there's no such thing as an unsigned short IIRC, but in C you can just cast the value as unsigned to get the value 246 instead of -10.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't have a base Object type. You will have to convert your strings all to a specific type.

```
std::string wtf[]= { std::string(a1, a1+ 1), std::string(st1, st1+ 1), std::string(str) }; // don't forget to #include <string>
```

Answer (score 1):

In C or C++ there is no common base class for all types (like Java's `Object`), the best you can use is `void* c[]=...;` (void* stands for untyped pointers, so it can hold anything) or explicitely cast to the desired type (but then it's undefined to access a short via a char-pointer).

Answer (score 0):

Although its highly not recommended, the rough equivalent of the las line in c is:

```
void*  c [] = {st1,str1,c2};
```